# Linq using Group by

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get the `Category` based total of the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Data>
- <Products>
  <Product ProductId="1001" ProductName="p1" category="A1" 
  ProductPrice="123.45" /> 

  <Product ProductId="1002" ProductName="p2" category="B1"
   ProductPrice="100.45" /> 

  <Product ProductId="1003" ProductName="p3" category="A1"
   ProductPrice="223.45" /> 

  <Product ProductId="1004" ProductName="p4" category="B1"
   ProductPrice="200.45" /> 
  </Products>
....
```

What is the modification needed to achieve it in the following ?(nothing is returned in 
my query)

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Product.xml");

 var sum = from p in doc.Descendants("Product")
           group p by p.Attribute("Category") 
           into g
           select new { category = g.Key,
           total = g.Sum(p =>(double)p.Attribute("ProductPrice")) };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample data shows an attribute of "category" but you're using "Category" in the query.

It looks like the query should nearly work other than that - although again I would *strongly* urge you to use `decimal` rather than `double` for the price.

EDIT: As Konamiman's now-deleted answer says, you need to group by the attribute *value* rather than the attribute itself. This code works (and uses decimal):

```
var sum = from p in doc.Descendants("Product")
          group p by p.Attribute("category").Value
          into g
          select new { category = g.Key,
                       total = g.Sum(p => (decimal) p.Attribute("ProductPrice"))
          };
```